# Alamofire, push a new request ahead of others queued

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I have an app that is firing a lot of initial Alamofire GET Requests to an API to eventually collect the data. However there are buttons on the app screen which also fire off POST requests to save etc. Though when i tap on the buttons, the alamofire requests take a long time to fire off due to the fact all the other GET Requests are still running.

Is it possible to make it so I can push the POST request ahead of the queue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using Alamofire or the underlying `URLSession` APIs. What you'd want to do is build your own request queue that lets you keep perhaps half a dozen requests in flight at any time. You would enqueue all of your `GET`s and then push your `POST`s to the front of the line when needed.

Comment: Ah would this be using something like an OperationQueue?? Like what you suggested here? https://github.com/ProcedureKit/ProcedureKit/issues/173#issuecomment-174792504

Comment: No, as `OperationQueue`s and `DispatchQueue`s don't have the ability to inject work at the before other work. At its simplest a queue is just a data structure with a beginning and end. All you really need is the ability to put something at the start of the queue to give it higher priority than already enqueued items.